# Questions about threadgroup memory in Metal

Tags: ios, memory, concurrency, gpgpu, metal

1. *Threadgroup memory* is shared between threads of a threadgroup, but is it preserved after the threadgroup finishes, allowing chaining (if I have a barrier let's say)?
2. It seems it is limited to 16KB on current devices, any workaround if I need more?
3. Does tiling interfer or influence the use of threadgroup memory in shaders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *Threadgroup memory is shared between threads of a threadgroup, but is it preserved after the threadgroup finishes, allowing chaining (if I have a barrier let's say)?*

No it's only available for the duration of the threadgroup execution.

2. *It seems it is limited to 16KB on current devices, any workaround if I need more?*

No. You would have to use a buffer in device memory.

3. *Does tiling interfer or influence the use of threadgroup memory in shaders?*

No (assuming you are referring to iOS tiled rendering)